# Regex Match Recurring Pattern with Small Variation

Tags: python, regex, python-3.9

I'm trying to match a repeating pattern with regex (in Python 3.9) which contains the same data in general but there are some areas which have varying iterations (specifically the lines beginning "CLD" and "REF".

I"m trying to match from "LIN" to the end of the line starting "HL" so I can carry out further matching on each iteration after.

This is an extract of the data I am using...

```
LIN**SI*ASN*BP*ITEM01*VP*1262702*CH*US
SN1**300*PC
PRF*5500015558****01
PID*F****DESCRIPTION01
REF*PK*000000051213
CLD*1*300*PLT71
REF*LS*0079393
HL*3*1*I
LIN**SI*ASN*BP*ITEM02*VP*1375541*CH*US
SN1**64*PC
PRF*5500014695****01
PID*F****DESCRIPTION02
REF*PK*000000051213
CLD*1*24*PLT71
REF*LS*0079393
CLD*1*40*PLT71
REF*LS*0079390
HL*4*1*I
```

My RegEx so far looks like this (although well short of what I'm trying to achieve)...

```
LIN.*\nSN.*\nPRF.*\nPID.*\nREF.*\n
```

However I got stuck at this point due to the varying number of "CLD" & "REF" lines and therefore it stops short of what I need and I'm pretty sure this is not efficient regex...

```
LIN**SI*ASN*BP*CH11979*VP*1262702*CH*US
SN1**300*PC
PRF*5500015558****01
PID*F****SEAL INTEGRAL
REF*PK*000000051213

LIN**SI*ASN*BP*CH10439*VP*1375541*CH*US
SN1**64*PC
PRF*5500014695****01
PID*F****PUMP AS PRIMING
REF*PK*000000051213
```

I also experimented with the regex below (from some Googling) to get around the varying occurrences and also be more efficient but it's not working...

```
LIN(.|\n)*HL.*
```

Can anyone help me pull this together?

Comment: `(?m)^LIN(?s:.*?)\nHL.*`? See https://ideone.com/07j6QO

Comment: Or repeat matching either REF or CLD `LIN.*\nSN.*\nPRF.*\nPID.*\n(?:(?:REF|CLD).*\n)+HL.*` https://regex101.com/r/k0xbYD/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
(?m)^LIN[\w\W]*?\nHL.* # For any Python version
(?m)^LIN(?s:.*?)\nHL.* # For Python 3.6+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jHRL7C/1/).

*Details*:

- `(?m)` - an inline `re.M` modifier flag that enables `^` to match any line start position
- `^` - start of a line
- `LIN` - `LIN` string
- `[\w\W]*?` / `(?s:.*?)` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `\n` - a newline
- `HL` - `HL`
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YB9D6d):

```py
import re
text = "LIN**SI*ASN*BP*ITEM01*VP*1262702*CH*US\nSN1**300*PC\nPRF*5500015558****01\nPID*F****DESCRIPTION01\nREF*PK*000000051213\nCLD*1*300*PLT71\nREF*LS*0079393\nHL*3*1*I\nLIN**SI*ASN*BP*ITEM02*VP*1375541*CH*US\nSN1**64*PC\nPRF*5500014695****01\nPID*F****DESCRIPTION02\nREF*PK*000000051213\nCLD*1*24*PLT71\nREF*LS*0079393\nCLD*1*40*PLT71\nREF*LS*0079390\nHL*4*1*I"
print(re.findall(r'(?m)^LIN(?s:.*?)\nHL.*', text))
```

Output:

```py
[
 
 'LIN**SI*ASN*BP*ITEM01*VP*1262702*CH*US\nSN1**300*PC\nPRF*5500015558****01\nPID*F****DESCRIPTION01\nREF*PK*000000051213\nCLD*1*300*PLT71\nREF*LS*0079393\nHL*3*1*I', 
 'LIN**SI*ASN*BP*ITEM02*VP*1375541*CH*US\nSN1**64*PC\nPRF*5500014695****01\nPID*F****DESCRIPTION02\nREF*PK*000000051213\nCLD*1*24*PLT71\nREF*LS*0079393\nCLD*1*40*PLT71\nREF*LS*0079390\nHL*4*1*I'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For varying iterations for *CLD* and *REF*, you could repeat 1 or more times  matching the lines that start with either of them using an alternation `|`, and a quantifier `+` to match at least 1 line.

```
^LIN.*\nSN.*\nPRF.*\nPID.*\n(?:(?:REF|CLD).*\n)+HL.*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `LIN.*\nSN.*\nPRF.*\nPID.*\n` Match the first 4 lines
- `(?:(?:REF|CLD).*\n)+` Repeat 1+ times matching either `REF` or `CLD`, the rest of the line and a newline
- `HL.*` Match `HL` and the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I5rf8N/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Mqdpuo)

For example

```
import re

s = ("LIN**SI*ASN*BP*ITEM01*VP*1262702*CH*US\n"
    "SN1**300*PC\n"
    "PRF*5500015558****01\n"
    "PID*F****DESCRIPTION01\n"
    "REF*PK*000000051213\n"
    "CLD*1*300*PLT71\n"
    "REF*LS*0079393\n"
    "HL*3*1*I\n"
    "LIN**SI*ASN*BP*ITEM02*VP*1375541*CH*US\n"
    "SN1**64*PC\n"
    "PRF*5500014695****01\n"
    "PID*F****DESCRIPTION02\n"
    "REF*PK*000000051213\n"
    "CLD*1*24*PLT71\n"
    "REF*LS*0079393\n"
    "CLD*1*40*PLT71\n"
    "REF*LS*0079390\n"
    "HL*4*1*I")
regex = r"^LIN.*\nSN.*\nPRF.*\nPID.*\n(?:(?:REF|CLD).*\n)+HL.*"
print(re.findall(regex, s, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
[
'LIN**SI*ASN*BP*ITEM01*VP*1262702*CH*US\nSN1**300*PC\nPRF*5500015558****01\nPID*F****DESCRIPTION01\nREF*PK*000000051213\nCLD*1*300*PLT71\nREF*LS*0079393\nHL*3*1*I',
'LIN**SI*ASN*BP*ITEM02*VP*1375541*CH*US\nSN1**64*PC\nPRF*5500014695****01\nPID*F****DESCRIPTION02\nREF*PK*000000051213\nCLD*1*24*PLT71\nREF*LS*0079393\nCLD*1*40*PLT71\nREF*LS*0079390\nHL*4*1*I'
]
```